# Align Nav-Bar to center of logo (Image)

Tags: html, css, uikit

I created a little test website with UIKit. Now that I messed around with that I wanted to try and create the design without using a pre-made framework. I am having issues with my navbar though.

This is the Original navbar that was created on the UIKit, see how the text is aligned vertically with the middle of the logo.
[image: Original navbar that was created on the UIKit]

This is the second image, which is the Navbar i am trying to create, as you can see the text is on the same row as the image, but it is aligned with the top of the image (logo) 
[image: the Navbar i am trying to create]

I am Trying to make the second image like the first image, the text aligned with the centre of the logo. I have tried "vertical-align: middle;" in my css but it doesn't seem to work... Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```css
html {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: honeydew;
}

nav .ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <nav>
      <ul class="column small-hidden large-12">
        <li class="column small-hidden large-3">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="column small-hidden large-1">Yep</li>
        <li class="column small-hidden large-1">Yep</li>
        <li style="float: center;" class="column small-hidden large-1 logo"><img alt="Website Logo" src="img/image.png"></li>
        <li class="column small-hidden large-1">Yep</li>
        <li class="column small-hidden large-1">Yep</li>
        <li class="column small-hidden large-3">&nbsp;</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can adjust the line-height of the li to a number that centers it with the image. such ass line-height:40px or so. Let me know if that works.

Comment: `li {
    vertical-align: top;
}`

Comment: Yes, that works thanks! But it pushes other things below it down, any way to stop that happening? Thanks! (In reply to Orlando P.) I haz kode, that seems to have no effect :/

Comment: make sure it's not being overridden / clear your cache https://jsfiddle.net/8kvftmqk/

Comment: I haz kode, I dont understand what you mean, the jsfiddle link you sent doesn't seem to fix the problem, the text is still aligned to the top of the image.

Comment: I see, reading your question I thought that it was what you're after. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/0sLam0of/

Comment: I haz kode, that is exactly what im looking for, but using that does not work on my code... I do not understand, any ideas?

Comment: try `li { vertical-align: top !important; }` for debugging just to rule out it being overwritten. Using `!important` is ok as long as you don't use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
nav li.img{ vertical-align: middle;}
```